# Yocto Linux: Building OS for Imx6 processor

Tags: linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m1Yp.png)I am new to yocto linux and I have been trying to install the yocto image for a imx6 processor.The manual for building the os is as follows:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin(this step may not be needed if the bin folder already exists)
  $ curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmoda+x ~/bin/repo
```

export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

```
$ mkdir fsl-release-bsp
$ cd fsl-release-bsp
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "Your Email"
$ git config --list
$ repo init -u git://git.freescale.com/imx/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp.git -b imx-3.10.53-1.1.0_ga
$ repo sync

$ MACHINE=imx6qsabresd source fsl-setup-release.sh -b build-x11 -e x11   
$ cd build-x11
$ bitbake fsl-image-qt5
```

at this command `MACHINE=imx6qsabresd source fsl-setup-release.sh -b build-x11 -e x11` I get MACHINE:command not found.
and if I skip this and run bitbake fsl-image-qt5
I get 
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

```
libsdl-native is set to be ASSUME_PROVIDED but sdl-config can't be found in PATH. Please either install it, or configure qemu not to require sdl.
```

ERROR: Execution of event handler 'check_sanity_eventhandler' failed
ERROR: Command execution failed: Exited with 1

pleease help if anyone knows how to build the os.

Comment: Are you sure you've typed that command verbatim? If you have a space between `MACHINE` and `=` you'll get command not found. If you don't it'll carry on with the `source` bit of the command.

Comment: I have tried both, without space and with space. Still the same error. My host machine is ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: A guess here, but might be worth trying `export MACHINE=imx6qsabresd` as one command then `source fsl-setup-release.sh -b build-x11 -e x11` on the next ?

Comment: please see the image attached. Thats the error im receiving now...

Comment: Thank you Greg...i had messed up with the .bashrc file and henceforth the error in that image...but the export MACHINE worked for me...